# OCaml function apparently works but does not return the expected result

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, matching

Who can help? I am a beginner in `OCaml`, I am trying to perform an action of unpacking sets. Having a set `[(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)]` I want to get the exit `[(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]`. I am using a script that I tested with Haskell and it worked, but in `OCaml`, it does not show the result. Where am I going wrong? I could not figure out where my mistake is. Thx.

```
let fst num1 num2 =
  match num1, num2 with
  | (x, y) -> x;;

let snd num1 num2 =
  match num1, num2 with
  | (x, y) -> y;;

let rec dcp_base list1 list2 list3 =
  match list1, list2, list3 with
  | (xs, ys, []) -> (xs, ys)
  | (xs, ys, z :: zs) -> dcp_base (xs @ [fst z]) (ys @ [snd z]) zs;; 

let descompact list =
  match list with
  | [] -> ([], [])
  | xs -> dcp_base [] [] xs;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fst` and `snd` functions are actually strange since you take two arguments to return the first one or the second one. I guess you wanted to get the first or second element of a pair so you should write (from most detailed to least detailed)

```ml
(* too much details *)
let fst num = match num with (x, y) -> x
let snd num = match num with (x, y) -> y

(* let's use the wildcards *)
let fst num = match num with (x, _) -> x
let snd num = match num with (_, y) -> y

(* do we really need num? *)
let fst = function (x, _) -> x
let snd = function (_, y) -> y

(* do we really need to match on a single pattern? *)
let fst (x, _) = x
let snd (_, y) = y
```

And it should work.

As a side note, `fst` and `snd` already exist in the standard library but it's never wrong to try implementing them yourself

Second side note, appending at the end of a list is usually not advised (not tail recursive, you're forcing the program to traverse the entire list to append an element at the end). What you could do instead is to add each new element at the head of the list and reverse the final list:

```ml
let rec dcp_base list1 list2 list3 =
  match list1, list2, list3 with
  | (xs, ys, []) -> (List.rev xs, List.rev  ys)
  | (xs, ys, z :: zs) -> dcp_base (fst z :: xs) (snd z :: ys) zs;;
```

And actually, since OCaml is really strong, you don't need `fst` and `snd` at all:

```ml
let rec dcp_base list1 list2 list3 =
  match list1, list2, list3 with
  | (xs, ys, []) -> (List.rev xs, List.rev  ys)
  | (xs, ys, (x, y) :: zs) -> dcp_base (x :: xs) (y :: ys) zs;;
```

Proof:

```ml
let rec dcp_base list1 list2 list3 =
  match list1, list2, list3 with
  | (xs, ys, []) -> (List.rev xs, List.rev  ys)
  | (xs, ys, (x, y) :: zs) -> dcp_base (x :: xs) (y :: ys) zs;; 

let descompact list =
  match list with
  | [] -> ([], [])
  | xs -> dcp_base [] [] xs;;

descompact [(1, 4); (2, 5); (3, 6)];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2; 3], [4; 5; 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your redefinition of `fst` and `snd`. They're not needed, as they're already defined in the standard library and in scope with exactly those names. But they're also wrong. Your implementation takes two arguments and selects either the first or second in a roundabout way by creating an intermediary tuple, instead of a singe tuple argument directly. Therefore, when you apply it to a single tuple argument it will return a partially applied function expecting the second argument.

You can fix the problem just by removing the definitions of `fst` and `snd` from your code, but if you absolutely want to reimplement it, it ought to look something more like this:

```
let fst (x, _) = x;;
let snd (_, y) = y;;
```